# Identity providers that work with Cosmosdb

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services, azure-cosmosdb, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-identity-3

What identity providers work with CosmosDB?   I have a Xamarin Forms Mobile app and an Angular 4 Web app that I want users to be able to log in to either to get at their data.  I want to avoid having to right a massive middle wear program, but resource token broker app would be ok.

I am surprised that there is no native support for Azure AD B2C.

I have tried using Azure AD B2C MSAL but it doesn't work very well and it's very buggy.  I would have thought this would have been high on Microsoft's to do list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB supports master keys (a primary/secondary but both have full control) and "resource tokens".  These resource tokens can be created by giving a user in Cosmos DB access to a specific resource.

See 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data

As for how to integrate with Azure AD B2C.  There is no native integration, Azure AD B2C cannot by itself issue resource tokens for Cosmos DB.  However I imagine you could implement a micro-service that would authenticate a user using Azure AD B2C, validate the ID token returned by Azure AD B2C and then use the Cosmos DB client library to generate a resource token.